# SMS sent via JSMPP not saved on a phone - "push" only

Tags: java, sms, jsmpp

I'm sending SMS via JSMPP as described in [SubmitMultipartMultilangualExample.java](https://github.com/uudashr/jsmpp/blob/master/jsmpp-examples/src/main/java/org/jsmpp/examples/SubmitMultipartMultilangualExample.java) provided by JSMPP authors. Current SMS is with latin symbols only and does not overlap 160 chars limit - no multipart message is sent, single one only.

So on mobile phone I see only push notification with Cancel and Save buttons (Android) or simply open message on my old Sony Ericsson. Text is delivered correctly, but message does not appear in "incoming" folder!

How to send ordinary SMS with no "hacks"?

Created also [issue on JSMPP's github](https://github.com/uudashr/jsmpp/issues/37).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed MessageClass.CLASS0 to MessageClass.CLASS1 at `GeneralDataCoding`'s constructor parameter and it's gone.

[Github comment](https://github.com/uudashr/jsmpp/issues/37#issuecomment-58907804) makes it clear: class 0 means "Flash SMS" which is not stored on a phone.

For further info refer to [github's issue](https://github.com/uudashr/jsmpp/issues/37).

Comment: Further testing gives that it's safer to use `new GeneralDataCoding(alphabet.value())` constructor for data coding because some SMPP providers do not understand compression and class bytes. `alphabet` is `Alphabet.ALPHA_UCS2` (0x08) for multilingual (Unicode) messages and `Alphabet.ALPHA_DEFAULT` (0x00) for latin. That sends ordinary SMS because it is used to be a default choise.